# PHP, preg_match to remove everything after colon?

Tags: php

Do you guys know if it's possible to remove everything after colon ":" in this preg_match?

The code make an new array based on an old array.
But the value is in this format `45656412124:464565445` and I only want the first part of the value (45656412124).

This is how I do today and I feel a bit stupid:

```
$mods = [];
    foreach($Query->GetRules() as $key => $val)
         if(preg_match('/MOD\d+_s/ui', $key))
              $mods[$key] = $val;

foreach($mods as $key => $val) {
    $mods[$key] = strstr($val, ':', true);
}
```

Comment: $mods[$key] = (explode(':', $val))[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate Regex so I use explode in these simple splits. Easy and clean.

```
$string="45656412124:464565445";
$result_array=explode(":",$string);
echo $result_array[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Regex:** `/^\d+/` here this regex means getting only digits(`\d+`) from the starting.

**Solution 1:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/780968)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string="45656412124:464565445";
preg_match("/^\d+/", $string,$matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

**Solution 2:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/780969)

```
<?php
$string="45656412124:464565445";
list($firstPart,$secondPart)=  explode(":", $string);
echo $firstPart;
```